# std::equality_comparable_with, std::totally_ordered_with, and strongly-typed integers

Tags: c++, c++20, strong-typing, c++-concepts

I'm defining a strongly-typed integer type while playing around with C++20 concepts, like below.

```cpp
class strong_int {
public:
    using integral_type = int;

    explicit strong_int( integral_type ) noexcept;

    explicit operator integral_type() const noexcept;

    constexpr auto operator<=>( const strong_int& ) const noexcept;

private:
    integral_type m_value;
};

constexpr auto operator<=>( const strong_int&, const int& ) noexcept;
constexpr auto operator<=>( const int&, const strong_int& ) noexcept;
```

However, I cannot use `strong_int` and `int` together in APIs expecting their parameters to be `std::totally_ordered_with` each other, because `std::totally_ordered_with<T,U>` expects that `std::common_reference_t<T,U>` exists. This does not hold for `strong_int` and `int` since the conversions between them are `explicit`. For example, the following fails:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
    requires std::totally_ordered_with<T1,T2>
void fn0( const T1&, const T2& );

void fn1() {
    strong_int si{0};
    int        i;

    fn0( si, i ); // compile error here
}
```

Is there a way to keep *both* the following?

- conversions between `strong_int` and `int` are `explicit`
- use `strong_int si` and `int i` in contexts that want `si` and `i` to satisfy `std::totally_ordered_with`

Comment: It's rather peculiar to have `strong_int_ == int_` but not have an implicit conversion from `int` to `strong_int`. Are you sure you cannot make that particular conversion implicit?